# Argument of undefined passed to parser was not a valid GraphQL DocumentNode

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, gql

This is my clientMutations.js file. I am using gql from @apollo-client.
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

```
const DELETE_CLIENT = gql`
  mutation deleteClient($id: ID!) {
    deleteClient(id: $id) {
      id
      name
      email
      phone
    }
  }
`;
```

Here is the component that uses the query.

```
import { DELETE_CLIENT } from "../mutations/clientMutations";

export default function ClientRow({ client }) {
  const { deleteClient } = useMutation(DELETE_CLIENT, {
    variables: { id: client.id },
  });
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{client.name}</td>
      <td>{client.email}</td>
      <td>{client.phone}</td>
      <td>
        <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onClick={deleteClient}>
          <FaTrash />
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

i am getting Invariant Violation: Argument of undefined passed to parser was not a valid GraphQL DocumentNode. You may need to use 'graphql-tag' or another method to convert your operation into a document in my browser console.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by restarting react. I had also made a mistake by using object destructuring rather than using array destructuring here:

```
  const [ deleteClient ] = useMutation(DELETE_CLIENT, {
    variables: { id: client.id },
  });
```